# Formio: Pre Filled Form (Dynamic Value)

Tags: formio

**Problem for: Formio (Community Edition)**

Say this is my form

```
1. Backend will dynamically fill up the first field 
2. User will fill up the rest of the fields
```

[image]

---

I could't find a way Formio does this, so I did something like this.

```
1. Generate a submission
2. Assign values
3. Assign owner
4. Now I can give this link to the user for filling
```

[image]

**Problem**:
1. Now If i have any mandatory validations, then it does not let me start a submission from the backend.

Is there a way to fix this or a work around?

Comment: [this](http://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/examples/externalload.html) seems to solve it but i need it for hosted on (community edition)

Comment: can you please look into this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650006/how-to-give-dummy-values-to-formio-form